# Is it good coding practice to do a BEGIN/COMMIT TRAN on an Single INSERT/SET? (SQL Server 2008)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transactions

I just noticed a Stored Procedure was using the following BEGIN/COMMIT TRAN.

```
BEGIN TRAN
  INSERT INTO SomeTable
     (
         TypeID
     )  
  VALUES
     ( 
         @TypeID
     )
    SET @OvID = SCOPE_IDENTITY() 
 COMMIT TRAN
```

Is it a good practice to use a Transaction on a INSERT and SCOPE_IDENTITY?

Will using a TRAN in this way slow down the INSERT process a lot?

I always think of using a Transaction when you have multiple statements that could fail (i.e. like two INSERTS). In this case, I can see the INSERT failing but I suspect the SCOPE_IDENTITY will always succeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a single statement it doesn't really matter, in that you aren't gaining any additional atomicity or reliability. And `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` can't be affected by anything outside of your current batch, so wrapping it in a `TRANS` block won't have any affect.

Whether it's a *good* practice to get into is rather subjective so I'm intentionally not addressing it!

Answer (score 2):

Transaction has a overhead, it will slow query time. For a single insert it is not necessary.
scope_identity will be null if insert fails.

Answer (score 2):

Your last point depends on what you mean by "succeed" - if the insert fails, *depending on the nature of the error and anything else going on in the scope/batch*, the assignment will happen, but `@OvID` will be `NULL`.

The transaction does have some overhead (I doubt you will notice the difference until you execute this thousands of times in a loop). But if this is code for a project in progress, the transaction wrapper may help to illustrate intent, e.g. if there are more statements that might be coming later, you no longer have this single-statement atomic transaction. Seems funny to bother with the transaction at all though if you're not going to bother with any `TRY/CATCH` or other error handling. I'd always want to handle the fallback just in case I leave an orphaned tx out there somehow. Weird things can happen depending on the source and severity of the failure.